# How to insert output of formatted print statement to a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have three lists and I am using printing the output using f-string formatting.

```
L = []
name = ['a', 'b', 'c']
dates = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'March']
event = ['Marriage', 'Office event', 'Birthday']
for a, b, c in zip(names, dates, event):
  print(f'I met {a} on {b} at this {c}')
  L.append(I met {a} on {b} at this {c})
```

How I am trying to insert the output to dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['string_values'])

print (df)
```

Comment: Just append the f-string to the list - `L.append(f"I met {a} on {b} at this {c}")`

Comment: list comprehension: `[f'I met {a} on {b} at this {c}' for a,b,c in zip(names, dates, event)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already got pointers as comments, here is a full answer:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'string_values': [f'I met {a} on {b} at this {c}'
                                     for a, b, c in zip(names, dates, event)]
                   })
```

output:

```
                         string_values
0      I met a on Jan at this Marriage
1  I met b on Feb at this Office event
2    I met c on March at this Birthday
```

using your (corrected) original code:

```
L = []
names = ['a', 'b', 'c']
dates = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'March']
event = ['Marriage', 'Office event', 'Birthday']
for a, b, c in zip(names, dates, event):
    L.append(f'I met {a} on {b} at this {c}')
df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['string_values'])
```